# How to fix too much space between images when using horizontal scroll

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a basic movie app using the OMDB api with a basic interface and search functionality implemented so far. When the results show up, there's a huge space between each movie poster. I'm still learning and cannot figure out how to fix this.

[The page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Ip0.png)

```
.movie-app > .row{
  overflow-x: auto;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

This is the css code I have used to implement the horizontal scroll.

```
const App = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  const getMovieRequest = async () => {
    const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchValue}&apikey=473e63b8`;

    const response = await fetch(url);
    const responseJson = await response.json();

    if (responseJson.Search) {
      setMovies(responseJson.Search);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovieRequest(searchValue);
  }, [searchValue]);

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid movie-app">
      <div className="row d-flex align-items-center mt-4 mb-4">
        <MovieListHeading heading="Movies" />
        <SearchBox searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} />
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <MovieList movies={movies} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

App.js

```
const MovieList = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {props.movies.map((movie, index) => (
        <div className="image-container d-flex justify-content-start m-3">
          <img src={movie.Poster} alt="movie"></img>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default MovieList;
```

Movie List component

Comment: What if you give your image-container (or the img) a width of fit-content? Tailwind css: **w-fit** or **max-w-fit**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#row-columns), the `row` class in bootstrap makes the columns inside the node equal-width as default. To make the columns be fit by content width of the node, try to use `row row-cols-auto`.

Instead of this:

```
  <div className="row">
    <MovieList movies={movies} />
  </div>
```

Try this instead:

```
  <div className="row row-cols-auto">
    <MovieList movies={movies} />
  </div>
```